# Symfony, assets doesn't include current folder in the url

Tags: php, symfony, assets

I'm working in a project that had Symfony 3.0.4, in this version we use asset to add the path of web folder to the assets like:

`{{ asset('filemanager/fileUploadedByAdmin.jpg') }}`

It works perfectly in production and in local servers (Wamp servers) generating urls like:

`http://localhost/projectName/web/filemanager/fileUploadedByAdmin.jpg`

Then the project was updated to the version 3.4.2 and now the same line generates something like:

`http://localhost/filemanager/fileUploadedByAdmin.jpg`

And the files aren't found. There is a way or configuration to get the same result in the 3.4.2 version?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
{{ absolute_url(asset('filemanager/fileUploadedByAdmin.jpg')) }}
```

to generate the absolute URL of an asset using `absolute_url` function.